# I want to upload audio files into S3 bucket using python api

Tags: python, api, amazon-s3

I want to upload files to S3 bucket and download files from S3 bucket using python api connected to html pages

Answer (score 1):

There is a library for this 'boto3', that upload files in S3. For quick setup of boto3 follow:

[boto3 quickstart](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html)

To upload a file :

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('filename', 'bucketname', 'desired filename in s3')
```